# How can I view who I am following on twitter?

Tags: twitter

How can I view who I am following on twitter?

I click home it says

[image]

I click profile it says

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Twitter keep redesigning their site and changing things.

It's still possible but what's not clear is that on profile, where it says how many are following and how many you are following, those are actually links.

You can click those and see.

[image]

So that text ^ where it says followers, and following, are actually links / you can click.